Woocommerce display Address1 (Street Name) and Address2 (House Numberg) on one line
I'm using Woocommerce and set the address2 field required and renamed it so I can use it as a field for the house number. So far so good.
The problem I have is I want to display this on 1 line and not on 2 lines. This happen in WP admin, in Woocommerce confirmation mails but also in packing slips/invoices that hooks the Woocommerce address format.
In what php file can I change this?

If you are using classic checkout, you can add the address2 value to the main address field value, using woocommerce_checkout_create_orderaction hook… There are many examples using this hook in stack overflow. You will need to use WC_Order getter and setter related methods to get and set the related values.
